# Visualizing my code in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

How do I visualize the class hierarchies I have written for my Xcode iPhone app project using Xcode 4?  Is there a visual class browsing tool?

Comment: :) I confirm both of the answers bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class browsing is built into XCode 4:

1. Open your project
2. In the top left corner of the left pane, click the icon that looks like a fat rectangle with two little squares dangling below:

[image: Class Browsing XCode 4]

Answer (score 2):

Omnigraffle can open an xcode project and do a pretty good job of drawing a class diagram.

Comment: Nice tip. Will check that out! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Open the Symbol Navigator (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. With the filter buttons in the bottom bar of the Symbol Navigator you can choose whether you want to browse the entire class hierarchy or just your project's classes.

Comment: this has a major fail when you use a framework like cocos2d and have to include hundreds of classes